# On using ConfuserEx combobox shows id's instead of values as dropdowns

Tags: winforms, obfuscation

I have used Confuserex to obfuscate my code which is using .net 4.5. Post compilation everything seems ok except for the behaviour of combobox (across all winforms i had in the project). The comboboxes are now showing id instead of the values as dropdowns. (Whereas these were running absolutely fine from visual studio in debug mode as well as the builds from the release mode).

In confuserex I have tried setting the  preset to Aggressive, Maximum ... but same issue irrespective of whichever preset i use.

Not putting any code here as there is no issue with the code per se. This is most likely a issue in Confuserex.

Is this a known issue and does a solution exists? Please let me know if any further details are required for providing help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to give you a singular answer, but perhaps I can steer you in the right direction:

In recently implementing ConfuserEx in a Winforms post-build event, I found that some third party controls were not displaying data correctly, or at all.  Like you, I changed the preset from Aggressive to Normal, to no avail.  I then went and excluded some of the methods that were binding data from obfuscation.  It alleviated the problem in some cases, on a data grid view and list box, specifically.  In those controls, I was receiving weird glitches like extra columns, cells rendered blank (with data present in the underlying object), et al.

All bets are off for third party controls with obfuscation - you'll never know if they will play ball or not.  Sometimes you'll experience this with .Net controls as well.  Obfuscation and Reflection also do not get along.  Perhaps check your combo box data bind technique, and lift the obfuscation from the method where it is being populated with data, if nothing else.  This is, of course, if you can live with this method being exposed.  Here's one way to do it:

```
    [System.Reflection.Obfuscation(Exclude = true)]
    public void MethodYouDontWantToObfuscate()
    {
      //Your method code
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Until just now I had a similar problem with WPF.

Our comboboxitems were in their own class. To solve the issue I added

```
[System.Reflection.Obfuscation(Exclude = true)]
```

in front of the class-declaration (like [MoSSBerG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37853033/on-using-confuserex-combobox-shows-ids-instead-of-values-as-dropdowns/38268871#38268871) suggested) and now everything works like a charm.